# Weird behaviour in Chrome regarding document.styleSheets

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, stylesheet

I've got this code...

```
function disableSheets(){
  console.log(document.styleSheets.length);
    var c = document.styleSheets.length;
    for(var i=0;i<c;i++){
      console.log(document.styleSheets[i]);
        if(typeof document.styleSheets[i]!=='undefined' && document.styleSheets[i].href.indexOf('stylezone')!=-1){
          document.styleSheets[i].disabled=true; 
        }
    }
    console.log(document.styleSheets.length);
}
```

When I run it in Firefox/Firebug it says:

```
3
StyleSheet
StyleSheet
StyleSheet
3
```

When I run it in Chrome/Developer Tools it says:

```
3
CSSStyleSheet
CSSStyleSheet
undefined
1
```

So my questions are:

1. Why would it say there are 3 stylesheets if the 3rd is undefined?
2. How did I lose 2 stylesheets by the end of that loop?
3. What happened to the 3rd sheet?

At the top of my HTML I have the 3 `<link>`s, linking the 3 stylesheets, and then immediately after that I call `disableSheets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, style sheets are removed from the `document.styleSheets` object (Chrome), when disabled.

Your code does actually read the first and third styleSheet:

An overview:

- 3 stylesheets: A, B, C
- `var c = document.styleSheets.length;`
- **Loop**, i=0
- `i=0`, Select `styleSheet[i]` = `StyleSheet A`
  2 stylesheets left: B, C
- **Loop**, i=1
- `i=1`, Select `styleSheet[i]` = `StyleSheet C`
  1 stylesheet left: B
- **Loop**, i=2
- `i=2`, Select `styleSheet[i]` = `undefined`
- **Loop** `i<3` = `break`
- `Console.log(document.styleSheets.length)` = `1` (Stylesheet B)

To get your code work, reverse the loop:

```
 for(var i=c-1; i>=0; i--){
```

Note: Initialise `i` at **`c-1`**! JavaScript array-like objects' indices are zero-based.

Comment: Oh..well that makes sense now. It's still problematic because I wanted to re-enable certain stylesheets later, but now that I know what the problem is, I can work around it. Thanks!

Comment: An easy work-around is to loop through all `<link>` (`rel=* stylesheet`) and `<style>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about the -webkit- bug for a while, I found a solution for it:

Just assigning document.styleSheets[n] to a global variable before disabling it , then it remains in the StyleSheetList.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `disable=true` on stylesheet removes it from document.styleSheets

It is a bug in Chrome, Safari

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88310